# How to get values from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Below is array that shows me tickets from a certain client. I'm trying to get a few values from it, I would like to get the total number of tickets from the ticket_id plus I would like to get the total of the total_time for all

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 7098246
        [ticket_date_time] => 2/20/2018 17:22:35
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => No Call
                        [caller_type] => Other
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 10:29:06
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 10:30:06
                        [total_time] => 00:01:00
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => No Call
                        [caller_type] => Other
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 10:30:06
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 10:42:03
                        [total_time] => 00:11:57
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 7139607
        [ticket_date_time] => 3/10/2018 21:50:05
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => Other
                        [caller_type] => Other
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 17:24:34
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 17:28:05
                        [total_time] => 00:03:31
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 7192893
        [ticket_date_time] => 4/3/2018 0:37:06
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => Inbound
                        [caller_type] => Guest
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 0:37:06
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 0:39:21
                        [total_time] => 00:02:15
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 7195274
        [ticket_date_time] => 4/3/2018 19:58:20
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => Inbound
                        [caller_type] => Guest
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 19:58:20
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 20:27:23
                        [total_time] => 00:29:03
                    )

            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 7195309
        [ticket_date_time] => 4/3/2018 20:06:44
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [call_type] => Inbound
                        [caller_type] => Guest
                        [start_time] => 4/3/2018 20:06:44
                        [end_time] => 4/3/2018 20:24:23
                        [total_time] => 00:17:39
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Could you just get the total number of tickets from the array length? So 5 for the example provided.

Comment: Post what you've tried to achieve that along with you expected output

Comment: Is this really going to be given to you hard coded as an array, or does it reside on a database somewhere?  It would make far more sense to use the database to answer this.

Comment: using the array length did work to get the number of tickets thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cannot test it here is my best bet :D

```
$totalTicket = count($arrayName);

$total_time = 0;

foreach ($arrayName as $array) { 

foreach ($array as $ticket)
{
    $total_time = $ticket['total_time'] + $total_time;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I wish I could have you test. Just not sure how all this works its fun trying tho. This is what I got when I tried what you had Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: did you change the name of $arrayName to your array variabel name ?

Comment: No I did not, sorry first time playing with this. In the above array I don't see any names.